# How to secure spring boot data rest security based on logged in user?

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-data-rest

I have a spring data rest micro-service, with following entities

- User
- Laptop
- Specs

User has list of laptops, and each one has it's own specs. Now the point is, user can log in through another micro-service, and get a JWT. Then, he creates a laptop for himself, and adds tech specs to the laptop.

Here's the call for adding the specs to the laptop

```
curl -i -X PUT http://localhost:8080/laptop/1/specs -H "Content-Type:text/uri-list" -d "http://localhost:8080/specs/1"
```

I can get my user's id from the JWT in my security filter, so how can I validate that the resource "belongs" to the user? How do I make sure that the user doesn't update other user's laptop specs? This is just the showcase, in fact number of models is around 30, so is there a dynamic solution to verify the user/resource association?

Here's the code of my security filter

```
public class JWTAuthenticationFilter extends GenericFilterBean {

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request,
                         ServletResponse response,
                         FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        Authentication authentication = JWTAuthenticationService.getAuthentication((HttpServletRequest) request);

        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);

        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

JWT validator

```
public static Authentication getAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request) {
    String authHeader = request.getHeader(AUTHORIZATION_HEADER);

    String authToken = authHeader != null ? authHeader.replace(TOKEN_PREFIX, "") : null;

    if (authToken != null) {

        Claims claims = Jwts.parser()
                .setSigningKey(SECRET)
                .parseClaimsJws(authToken)
                .getBody();

        String username = claims.getSubject();

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") final List<String> authoritiesClaim = (List<String>) claims.get(AUTHORITIES);

        final List<SimpleGrantedAuthority> authorities = authoritiesClaim
                .stream()
                .map(SimpleGrantedAuthority::new)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        return username != null ?
                new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, null, authorities) :
                null;
    }
    return null;
}
```

and web security configuration

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.cors().and().csrf().disable().authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .addFilterBefore(new JWTAuthenticationFilter(),
                    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
}
```

Comment: What have you tried? In spring boot you can just use spring-security yml to set everything.

Comment: I have added a filter and I parse the JWT to Spring Authentication, but I don't know what to do further

Comment: So your user should be authenticated at that point how do you authorize?

Comment: just updated the code, here's how I get my user, but I don't know how to add resource relation based security. if user A is authenticated, he can actually update user B's resource

Comment: for roles, which it looks to me like what you trying to do, you can have custom headers in the jwt to say user has this role and then in your validator do authorization logic.

Comment: can you give a sample how can I validate ANY resource? not doing switch for url, and parse with regex to find out what the user is trying to do and then validating the relation?

Comment: @Carmine, what you are looking for is **Authorization**. You will have to use [method security](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#el-access), and annotate service methods with [`@PreAuthorize("hasPermission('#laptopId', 'OWNER')")`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#el-pre-post-annotations) and add a [`PermissionEvaluator` implementation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#el-permission-evaluator) to decide whether current user should be allowed access.